# How to tell if a device supports Assisted GPS, and if how to get the Assisted GPS cooridinates?

Tags: gps, assisted-gps

1)  Is Assisted GPS implemented at the hardware and OS level, or is it a hardware and secondary software thing.  I've never used this so wondering what is required to 'access' this.  I noticed a [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_devices_with_Assisted_GPS) article so is seems it is very device specific, but wondering if this is full and complete list.

2) How are the aGPS value accessed?  Are they streamed through a diff port (v. true GPS)?  Is that configurable?

I tried to ask appropriate questions to understand more about this, but I'm kind of lacking context so my questions may need some edits from some who knows more about this.

thanks
df

Comment: A-GPS-enabled receiver will use a data connection (Internet or other) to contact the assistance server for A-GPS information -  Some A-GPS devices do not have the option of falling back to standalone or autonomous GPS